# How to retrieve the missing column or missing table from an invalid package in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are invalid objects in my table like packages or procedures, would I be able to retrieve the missing tables or fields that the package requires using sqlplus script or an sql script?

Comment: The errors on the invalid objects are ORA-00942: table or view does not exist and ORA-00904:string: invalid identifier.

Comment: You may want to edit your post to include updates instead of posting updates by comment

Answer (score 1):

First, try to compile to schema to get the smallest set of errors:

```
CONN myuser/mypass@mydb
EXEC UTL_RECOMP.recomp_serial(USER);
```

Next, you can get a list of all the outstanding errors:

```
SELECT * FROM user_errors;
```

Now, this will show you the object (package, procedure, error), and the line number with the error. You can join this to user_source for example to get show the lines of code, for example (not tested - shown here just for a hint):

```
select e.error_text, s.type, 
       s.name, s.line, e.line
from user_errors e, user_source s
where s.name = e.name
and  s.type = e.type
and  s.line between (e.line-2) and (e.line+2) -- context 
order by s.type, s.name, e.line, s.line;
```